# How to install PDO_PGSQL for PHP 8 on Mac OS Big Sur having M1 Chip?

Tags: php, postgresql, macos, php-8

I have been trying to install pdo_pgsql. Homebrew is not working. Adminer needs this extension for accessing the DB.  How to solve the issue?

PgSQL and PDO_PgSQL extensions are already enabled on the php.ini file. But, still, Adminer shows the Error:

> None of the supported PHP extensions (PgSQL, PDO_PgSQL) are available.

When running $ php artisan serve, it shows the following error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_pgsql (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_pgsql, 9): image not found), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on this one, but in case anyone happens across it, I'll answer it anyway.

Managing PHP on MacOS with homebrew can be a bit of a pain, but it can be made easier.

[I've answered this question in great detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70198978/9897665), but to summarise:

- Remove what you currently have installed and any existing taps to PHP repositories.
- Tap the shivammathur/php repository using `brew tap shivammathur/php`
- Install the PHP version you're after (e.g. `brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1`)
- Link it using `brew link`

The PHP versions available through that tap include pgsql if I'm not mistaken.

For other extensions:

- Tap the extensions repository: `brew tap shivammathur/extensions`
- Install the extension you need: e.g. `brew install xdebug@8.2`